# Convert JSON contents into HTML

Tags: json, angularjs

This has probably been asked a load of times for, so forgive me for asking again.

I have a need to display the contents of a Json string as a formatted HTML fragment. It will be purely a read only view, the Json will vary as well.

I have seen modules out there that deal with form generation based of Json schemas but in my case there is no schema.

Is there anything out there anyone can recommend?

Comment: Loop, create HTML, append.

Comment: define `formatted html` , not clear what you are really looking for

Comment: Sorry I meant displaying the values in the Json appropriately, using the most suitable elements. But thinking more about it things like dates will be coming back as encoded strings etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a library to use a quick google search found this. 
[www.json2html.com](http://www.json2html.com/)

I'm not sure if you are trying to use json data that pre-exists or starting from scratch as you did not provide an example but if you are starting from scratch this might be a good tool to design around.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too limited, but if you're just looking for a pretty-printed view of your json, JSON.stringify supports that out of the box.  I use this custom filter:

```
.filter('pretty', function () {
    return function (json) {
        return JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2);
    };
})
```

`<pre ng-bind="myData | pretty"></pre>`

Comment: why do that when angular already has a built in `json` filter ? `<pre>{{myData|json}}</pre>`

Comment: I... did not know that existed.  Now I feel pretty silly.

Comment: very handy for printing objects in view while developing

Comment: yeah, I reinvented the wheel there :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across anything standalone that does this in a generic sense... my approach has been to 'roll my own' so to speak and build to suit my needs like so:

```
$.each(retrievedStatusData, function(i, val){
    $('ul').append('<li class="gamer-list-item">' + val.gamertagis + '</li>');
    $('li').eq(i).prepend('<img src="' + val.gamercard.gamerpicSmallImagePath + '" class="gamer-pic">');
});
```

... which would produce an unordered list with the gamertag / name and a small thumbnail photo for each object in the JSON data source Im working with.

Now I HAVE on occasion, when inspecing JSON structures at a birds eye view sometimes done a loop over JSON and used sort of a for each key loop that displays ALL the JSON data in a 2 column table, the key on the left and value on the right.  But that is only really useful for simple JSON data I guess.